# asp.net mvc file upload security breach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ok apart from checking the file type and file size both server side how can i avoid security breach during uploading of file that may compromise my system (basically from the advance hacker) . is this enough? . i am not talking about any special scenario just simple file upload.

Well security is one of the major concern in my application.

Comment: Are you going to be hosting these files?  As in - allowing other users to download them?

Comment: in some places yes like cv and in some places no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make sure you don't store those files to a folder which is publicly accessible and executable by the web server. Also you could use heuristics by checking the first few bytes of the file for known file formats. For example common image formats have standard beginning headers so you might check for the presence of those headers.